# Как сделать луч радара?

Tags: java, javafx

Каким образом можно было бы реализовать луч индикатора кругового обзора радара? т.е., не просто прямая, а что-то вроде сектора круга, который вращается.

Проблема в том, что можно этот сектор создать двумя лучами, но не знаю как сделать ему заливку, чтобы потом выставить ему прозрачность. Возможно, у вас есть другие идеи, я бы с радостью их выслушал.

Comment: Ну простейший способ - лучи до каждой точки на окружности внутри сектора - вот вам и заливка

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно запоздалый ответ, но вдруг кому пригодится:

1) [javafx.scene.shape.Arc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Arc.html)

2) [javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/SVGPath.html)

```
SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();
svg.setContent( "m 0,0 a 100,100 0 0 1 100,100 l -100,0 z" );
```

Чтобы самому строку контента не составлять, можно нарисовать необходимую фигуру в векторным графическом редакторе( например Inkscape ) и глянуть его XML описание.